# Reduction modulo p - common divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $\mathbb{Z}[X]\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[X]=\mathbb{F}_p[X], \sum c_iX^i\mapsto\sum \overline{c_i}X^i$ be the homomorphism "reduction modulo p" with $p$ being a prime. We furthermore have, $h(X^p)=f\cdot g$ where each polynomial is monomial. We also have $deg f=n$ and $p$ does not divide $n$.

My book states: "The equation $\overline{h}(X^p)=\overline f \cdot \overline g $ shows that $\overline h$ and $\overline f$ have a common divisor in $\mathbb{F_p}[X]$."

I can not figure out why this holds. I might have overseen something obvious, but I don't even have an idea.

EDIT: Also, $\zeta$ is a root of both $f$ and $h(X^p)$.

Comment: I think you need to use $\bar{h}(X^p)=(\bar{h}(X))^p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting!

---

We just need to prove:
$$h(x^p)\in (\bar{h}(x)),$$
where $(\bar{h}(x))$ is an idea. 
In fact, as Krish's comment, $\bar{h}(x^P)=(\bar{h}(x))^p$.

This is because we can use algebraic closed field to analysis. And 
$h(x)=(x+\lambda_1)\cdots(x+\lambda_n), h(x^p)=(x^p+\lambda_1)\cdots(x^p+\lambda_n)$.

As fermat's small theorem :
$$ \lambda^p\equiv\lambda (mod\quad p)$$
Therefore,
$$(x^p+\lambda)=(x+\lambda)^p,$$
in $Z_p[x]$.So $\bar{h}(x^P)=(\bar{h}(x))^p$.

Comment: I forgot to add, that $\zeta$ is a common root of $f$ and $h(X^p)$. Your answer then implies that $\zeta$ is also a root of $\overline f$ and $\overline h$. Is this correct? This would then mean, that $\overline f$ and $\overline h$ have a factor in common.

Comment: its correct. of course！